# Show Contentful product using GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, contentful, gatsby

I am pulling in data from Contentful api into gatsby and all seems to be tracing out fine. However when I implement the component that pulls in the contentful data on to my index.js file I keep getting an undefined error.

```
WebpackError: Cannot read property 'allContentfulProduct' of undefined
```

Product.js:

```
import React from "react"

const Product = ({data}) => {
  const assets = data.allContentfulProduct.edges[0].node
  const { productName } = assets;

 return (
    <div>
      {productName}
    </div>
  )
};

export default Product;



export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query ImageAPIExamples {
    allContentfulProduct {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          productName
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Index.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import Products from '../components/products/image';

const IndexPage = props =>
  (<main>
    Hello
  </main>);

export default IndexPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like I was able to solve this by passing props and querying the data on the index.js page.

Solution:

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Products from '../components/products/image';


const IndexPage = props =>
  (<main>
    <Products data={props.data.allContentfulProduct.edges[0].node} />
  </main>);

export default IndexPage;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {
    allContentfulProduct {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          productName
          image {
            file{
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: You can only fetch data from GraphQL from components that are given to `createPage()` and export the `pageQuery` magic variable. If your `Products.js` was imported from `index.js` then it cannot fetch from GraphQL. This is to allow Gatsby to statically compile your data.